# SSRS Change Fill Colour Depending on Cell Values

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, conditional-formatting

I'm aware this has been asked a few times however I'm struggling to find an answer to what I need it for (Or maybe I have missed the answer so please feel free to copy and paste a link if has already been asked)

I'm aware through searching on here the `Switch` function can help change the colour of the background depending on the value.  I have 3 colours needed, however one seems to over ride the other which is causing the issue, and I think this is because one value is in between two numbers

I'm trying to show

Equal or greater than 10 - Red
Equal to or greater than 5 until 9.99 - Amber
Equal or greater than 0 until 4.99 Green
Less than 0 until -4.99 Green
-5 until -9.99 Amber
-10 or greater Red

I'm using this but it isn't working;

```
=switch(Fields!Field_Name <= -10, "Red",  
Fields!Field_Name <= -5, "Amber",
Fields!Field_Name >= 10, "Red", 
Fields!Field_Name >= 0, "Green", 
Fields!Field_Name <= 4.99, "Green",
Fields!Field_Name < -0.1, "Green",
Fields!Field_Name <= -4.99, "Green",
Fields!Field_Name > 5, "Amber", True, "Green")
```

Any help (and not ridicule) would be really appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: What type of query source are you working with: T-SQL, PL\SQL, XML, etc.?

Comment: If it's SQL, I would do the logic in a `CASE` statement in the query.

Comment: Also, it looks like your missing the `.Value` on the end of `Fields!Field_Name`

Comment: Sorry all, Yes its SQL Using SSMS SQS Server 2012 and inputting into SSRS Visual Studio 2013

Comment: @aduguid Yes, the above is just sample code made up on the spot while writing the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find, sometimes it helps to draw out where you want the colours in a range. Then work from outer most conditions inward.

[image: screenshot]

Here's an example of how I would test with a T-SQL `CASE` expression. I think this logic is what you're after. I've also included an example as an expression.

#### SQL Example:

```
WITH
source_data
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( -11, 'Red')
    , ( 11, 'Red')
    , ( -6, 'DarkOrange')
    , ( 6, 'DarkOrange')
    , ( 1, 'Green')
    , ( 4.98, 'Green')
    , ( -0.11, 'Green')
    ) tbl ([Field_Name], [FillColourWanted]) 
)
SELECT
      [Field_Name] = CAST([Field_Name] AS FLOAT)
    , [FillColourWanted]
    , [FillColour] = 
        CASE 
            WHEN [Field_Name] <= -10 OR [Field_Name] >= 10 THEN 'Red'
            WHEN [Field_Name] <= -5 OR Field_Name >= 5 THEN 'DarkOrange'
            WHEN [Field_Name] < 5 OR [Field_Name] > -5 THEN 'Green'
        END 
FROM
    source_data
```

#### SQL Results:

[image: screenshot]

#### Expression Example:

```
=Switch(
  Fields!Field_Name.Value <= -10 OR Fields!Field_Name.Value >=10, "Red"
, Fields!Field_Name.Value <= -5 OR Fields!Field_Name.Value >= 5, "DarkOrange"
, Fields!Field_Name.Value > -5 OR Fields!Field_Name.Value < 5, "Green"
)
```

#### SSRS Results

The background colour for `[FillColourWanted]` and `[FillColor]` are set by the values from the SQL columns. The background colour for `[Expression]` is set by the expression example.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is beyond brilliant for understanding how to do it and what I needed.  Thank you very much @aduguid Alas I've not got enough of a profile to mark this up etc, but if anyone else can that would be great.  thanks again

Comment: Alas this hasn't worked.  anything between 0.00 and 5 is coming as no fill whatsoever.  Can you think of what will be stopping this?

Comment: Yeah it's just plain white with black text which is a damn shame as the others work fine

Comment: Ignore that, I've got it working, don't know why it didn't at first

Comment: Ah thank you! didn't know I could do that, thought I could only up vote it.  done!

Comment: Thanks. You may be interested in one of my GitHub projects for reporting services. I keep a bunch of example reports in it as well as a wiki. https://github.com/SQL-Server-projects/Reporting-Services-examples

Comment: I'll keep an eye on that, by a quick glance I think there would be someuseful items on there for me

Comment: Ah I've ran into an issue on something similar I'm working on - when using the following expression, if it's between -1 and 1 I need the cell fill colour to be green, however it seems to come back red -       =switch(
  Fields!P1R1_Valuedifference.Value <= -1 OR Fields!P1R1_Valuedifference.Value > 1, "LightCoral"
, Fields!P1R1_Valuedifference.Value > -1 OR Fields!P1R1_Valuedifference.Value < 1, "PaleGreen")

Comment: Ignore me, I was using the wrong column name - however hve seen the 'me.value. option and this has worked a treat =switch(Me.value <= -1.0, "LightCoral",
Me.Value > 1.0, "LightCoral", True, "LightGreen")

Comment: Cool, when I have to debug stuff like that, I usually remove all but one condition and then add each condition and check the results per update.